# How to save and load again data on views when back many times in iOS

Tags: ios

I'm working on a project that has many view controllers. Suppose that they are:
A -> B -> C -> D -> E ->F ->G -> H. Each of them has a back and a next button to switch to another view and has many text fields.

I typed text into every textfield. From H view, I can go back to previous views by popviewcontroller and review typed data. but when I click on next button again, all of data on the view were lost. I need to back/next continuous without losing data. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Create a Singleton class.

Give in Singleton class a property like `Form *form;`
If you start your first ViewController create a new Form

```
[Singleton sharedInstance].form = [[Form alloc] init];
```

On leave first ViewController set property from TextField

```
[Singleton sharedInstance].form.name = textField.text
```

On leave second ViewController set property

```
[Singleton sharedInstance].form.mail = textField.text
```

In each ViewController in viewWillAppear method set stored text

```
self.textField.text = [Singleton sharedInstance].form.name
```

or

```
self.textField.text = [Singleton sharedInstance].form.mail
```

It's a simple example, but hope it helps to understand what is to do :)

Answer (score 0):

What about using a NSMutableDictionary to keep the models for each view controller as a key value pair. And Each View Controller initialized with this NSMutableDictionary

```
- (id) initWithDataDictionary:(NSMutableDictionary *)aDataDictionary
{
  self = [super init];

  _myDataModel = (MyDataModel*)[aDictionary valueForKey:@"MyKeyName"];

  if(_myDataModel == nil)
  {
    _myDataModel = [MyDataModel alloc] init];
    aDataDictionary setValue:_myDataModel forKey:@"MyKeyName"];
  }
  return self;
}

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];

 [self displayData];
}

- (void) displayData
{
  self.text1.text = _myDataModel.name;
}
```

You may also able to keep a key-value pair for setting focus to a last focused textfield.

Comment: Won't the data dictionary gets refreshed/emptied going back and forth between views?

Comment: The idea is to pass the dictionary from A -> B -> C -> D -> E ->F ->G -> H. So all these controllers have a same instance of the NSMutableDictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I see two options here:

- If you use storyboards [unwind](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/10/25/ios-unwind-segues/) segues are very good option.
- Else you can create own [delegate](http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/delegate.html).